# Scaled div overflows on Microsoft IE/Edge

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  .foo {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f00;
    width: 2000px;
    height: 50px;
    transform-origin: left;
    left: 0;
    transform: scaleX(0.1);
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="foo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

On most browsers it works fine. But on Microsoft IE/Edge, a horizontal scroll bar appears despite the width of the div is smaller than the screen width. How do I get rid of it?

I have to use transform: scaleX, since the size and position of the div are calculated based on some conditions using JavaScript. The script, however, will guarantee the div never goes out of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `overflow-x: hidden;` to disable that.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `-ms-overflow-style: none;` to avoid the horizontal scroll bar.

```
   body {
        -ms-overflow-style: none;
    }
```

For more about the attribute, you could refer to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-ms-overflow-style

[image: the result]